# Start animation when target is found

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, target, vuforia

I'm using Unity and Vuforia, and would like to make an animation on AR object that starts when target is found and resets when target is lost so that, when target is found again the animation starts from the beginning.

This is the code of the DeafaultTrackableHandler:

```
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{

    // Begin sound

    public AudioSource soundtarget;
    public AudioClip cliptarget;
    private AudioSource[] allAudioSources;


    // Function to stop all sounds
    void StopAllAudio(){
        allAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType (typeof(AudioSource)) as AudioSource[];
        foreach (AudioSource audioS in allAudioSources) {
            audioS.Stop ();
        }
    }

    // Function to play sound
    void playSound(string ss){
        cliptarget = (AudioClip)Resources.Load (ss);
        soundtarget.clip = cliptarget;
        soundtarget.loop = false;
        soundtarget.playOnAwake = false;
        soundtarget.Play ();
    }

    // -------- end sound -----------


    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

        soundtarget = (AudioSource)gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource> ();
    }

    #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    ///     tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PRIVATE_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        if(mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName == "MERCADO")
            playSound("sounds/audio");
    }


    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas':
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        StopAllAudio ();
    }

    #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
}
```

With this code it happen that when I detect the target, the animation started before, and when the target is lost, the animation doesn´t start from the beginning.

Thank you so much for the help. ☺

Comment: Hi @Milagros, welcome to **StackOverflow**. Thanks for taking the time of writing a good question!, just a little detail - you may add the tag of the language you're using _(I don't use Unity but I believe this is **C#**)_. So, your code snippet will get syntax highlight, _(that can help a lot to many people reading your question)_, and also will bring more attention to your question. Cheers.

Comment: I don't see anything about an animation in your code. I assume you are using an `Animator`? You are only disabling the colliders, canvases and renderers but the animator will go on playing the animation you just don't see it anymore

Comment: @derHugo I was trying to put the code of the Animator, but I don´t know how. What I need to add in my code? Thanks